# PR creation from workorder for Material linetype

Tags: maximo

In Maximo, Workorder application, I created one record with material line type in plans tab.
after I approved the workorder, from more actions I selected view->PO information, it is not showing/else its not generating the PR.

Please assist if you know.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programming questions and answers that come with a [example]. You need to go to [IBM's Maximo community](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/iot/communities/community-home/digestviewer?CommunityKey=3d7261ae-48f7-481d-b675-a40eb407e0fd) or [MORE Maximo](https://moremaximo.com/communities/community-home?CommunityKey=784e8753-d7af-4281-8463-e86f3b5d7076) and ask your Maximo functionality questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Either the Direct Issue flag is set for your work material and the Reorder cron task has not been configured to run or has not run yet, or the material is from a storeroom that has enough stock to cover your material requirement without causing a reorder.